# How to use Heruko with Docker API (Python SDK) of my local machine?

Tags: python, rest, api, docker, flask

I'm trying to display some docker' information on the browser with flask .

```
       . . .

@app.route('/version')
def work():

    client = docker.from_env()
    if client.ping() :
        return client.info()
    else :
        return "Not working"
       . . .
```

It was working fine

the **QUESTION** is : how to connect docker daemon of my machine with the flask app after deploying it on **Heroku**  .. and how I can set a URL to the Docker server

Answer (score 0):

Port mapping, then open the browser and enter the address and port